# PHP crosstab formatting from array

Tags: php, arrays, crosstab

Hi I have a PHP array like this

```
$table=array();
$subject_names=array();

$subject_names[118]="English";
$subject_names[108]="Software Engeneering";

$table['Josh'][118]['int'] =55;
$table['Josh'][118]['ext'] = 10;
$table['Josh'][108]['int'] =45;
$table['Josh'][108]['ext'] = 12;

$table['Matt'][118]['int'] =45;
$table['Matt'][118]['ext'] = 12;
$table['Matt'][108]['int'] =50;
$table['Matt'][108]['ext'] = 15;
```

Here 118 and 108 are subject_id I am trying to format it like this

```
    student |       English           |   Software Engeneering |
            | int. mark | ext. mark   | int. mark | ext. mark  |
    ___________________________________________________________
    Josh    | 55        | 10          | 45        | 12
    Matt    | 45        | 12          | 50        | 15
```

I tried

```
echo "Student Name\t";

foreach($subject_names as $sub_name)
{
    echo "$sub_name\t";
}
echo "<br>";    

foreach($table as $sname => $subjects){

    echo "$sname\t";

    foreach($subjects as $subject_name => $types)
    {
        foreach($types as $marks)
        {
            echo "$marks\t";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```

It working fine but if I change the position of array item of table like

```
$table['Josh'][118]['int'] =55;
$table['Josh'][108]['int'] =45;
$table['Josh'][118]['ext'] = 10;
$table['Josh'][108]['ext'] = 12;
```

It won't give a correct result. Is there anyway to assure that the result are always correct.

Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Comment: I'm going to assume you **are not** hard coding these values by default, but rather pulling from a database? The issue you're having here is that you code expects that everything is in perfect order. If you are expecting stuff out of order you'll need to sort it first. If that's a case you expect to happen then I'll gladly give more help if you need it.

Comment: Yes exactly I am pulling these value from database. I will greatly appreciate your any help.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to make sure you're correctly sorting your database values ... i.e. `ORDER BY student, class_id, mark_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I wrote for your request, picking the scores using the `$subject_names` as control rather than the students' scoresheet (I hope you get what I mean after going through the codes)...

```
$table=array();
$subject_names=array();

// notice that I switched subject order, just to show that subjects control the marks displayed thereby ensuring consistent score mapping
$subject_names[108]="Software Engeneering";
$subject_names[118]="English";

// and I'm using the rearranged scores (the sample use-case you specified in the question that distorts your output)
$table['Josh'][118]['int'] =55;
$table['Josh'][108]['int'] =45;
$table['Josh'][118]['ext'] = 10;
$table['Josh'][108]['ext'] = 12;

$table['Matt'][118]['int'] =45;
$table['Matt'][118]['ext'] = 12;
$table['Matt'][108]['int'] =50;
$table['Matt'][108]['ext'] = 15;

echo "Student Name\t";

foreach($subject_names as $sub_name)
{
    echo "$sub_name\t";
}
echo "\n";

// proposed solution:
foreach($table as $sname => $subjects){

    echo "$sname\t";

    foreach ($subject_names as $subject_id => $name) {

        foreach ($subjects[$subject_id] as $mark) {
            echo "$mark\t";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";

}
```

Here's the output of the script above...

```
Student Name    Software Engeneering    English 
Josh    45  12  55  10  
Matt    50  15  45  12
```

Running the same data through the script provided in the question, here's the output (distorted)...

```
Student Name    Software Engeneering    English
Josh    55  10  45  12
Matt    45  12  50  15
```

*P.S: 'Engeneering' should be 'Engineering'*

I hope I've been helpful.
Cheers!

Comment: Correcting the order of his data isn't helping him. The problem has is when is data is out of order.

Comment: Please read the codes... I rearranged the data to show that my algorithm is unaffected by data order, did not *correct* it

Comment: Not nice to downvote what you don't understand @Augwa

Comment: I guess it works, but it is still a bad answer :) 3 nested foreach loops, that will exponentially get horrible performance. Consider Harvard for 2016. 22000 students, 8000 courses, 6 course per student. 1,056,000,000 iterations.

Comment: Accepted. But the questioner said nothing about performance being his problem, he clearly used three nested foreach loops in his sample @Augwa

Comment: @ Banjo Mofesola Paul  your answer will assure that subject mark will be in correct order as the header, thanks

Comment: Banjo he used 3 loops to say what's he's done. Taking what he's done to create more bad code is why you got the down vote. If you want a neutral response or an up vote come up with a better answer.

Comment: The focus should be on solving his problem, I suppose, not on creating further problems

Comment: One more question hope you will don't mine is it possible to add some more information in this array $table['Josh'][118]['int'] =55; like $table['symbol_no'] = 'JH001'; current I am doing like $table['Josh#JH001'][118]['int']  ; explode it to get name & symbol_no is there any better idea?